# How can we underline Lables (x-axis) in Chart Js

Tags: reactjs, charts

How can we add underline in `Lables (x - axis)` in `ReactJS` .

I am expecting for solutions.

Comment: Which chart lib you are using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.